# choose comet framework for java

Tags: java, comet, server-push

As i want to implement a solution in which server constantly push Stock Quotes to mulitple clients , 
while exploring i came to across few framework , but what would be the good choice to 
i am using

Server Side : Glassfish 3.1
Client Side : ExtJs/Jquery
Url Pattern : Rest

[Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)

[Grizzly](http://grizzly.com/)

[Servlet 3.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html)

As i am totally confused as i don't know which one is scalable and efficient , so could anyone suggest me among them or a new one

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at frameworks which build a client-server like Netty (in Java) and then use HTTP push or potentially even websockets.